# event prevent default not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
        history.pushState({url: 'index.html'},'','page1.html');
    });
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
});
```

When `e.preventDefault()` is removed, the hash tag will appear after like `localhost/page1.html#` , but when `e.preventDefault()` is added, `e.originalEvent.state` will appear as `null`

```
<a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
```

What is the problem? How do I solve it?

EDITED:

When the button is pressed, the address bar updated(That's good). However, when I hit the back button, the state object appears as null(It suppose to show {url: 'index.html'})

Comment: So, what you're really saying is that event.preventDefault() IS working, it's just that when you use it, it adversely affects your popstate event.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do, with this code?

Comment: I can't recreate your problem. It isn't null. http://jsfiddle.net/Kd3vw/5/show/

Comment: @KevinB It is, it says PopStateEvent {state: null,.... in Google Chrome Console

Comment: unfortunately (or, maybe fortunately,) i see an object, in google chrome.

Comment: I see. Of course state is null, the first state is null. that isn't a bug. The state you went to was '/', which didn't have a state object. I didn't see it at first because i clicked 3-4 times.

Comment: But didn't I already pushed state? What should I do to solve this :/?

Comment: ... there's nothing to solve. when you go back to the original state, the state object will be null because... it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing isn't a bug, it's the intended behavior.

When you first load the page, the state is `/` and the state object is null. when you click on the anchor tag with `preventDefault`, the state is changed to `/page1.html` and is given an object to store. Now, when you press back button, the popstate event happens after the state has changed back to `/`, which doesn't have a state object!

To demonstrate, click the link 3-4 times. Now, each time you hit back, `originalEvent.state` will have an object until you get back to `/`, which of course doesn't have a state object.

To make the default state have a state object instead of null, use replaceState.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
        history.pushState({url: 'index.html'},'','page1.html');
    });
});
$(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
    console.log(e.originalEvent);
});
// give the current state a state object
history.replaceState({url: 'index.html'},'','');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd3vw/6/